# Templated Intermediate Array for Given Type

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, c++14

I have a library that contains a function:

```
// Gets [bytes] number of *bytes* and fills rx_buff
void getData(uint8_t* rx_buff, uint16_t bytes);
```

I also have a library that I am writing an interface for, the structure is rather simple (protected IP, all names are imaginary):

[libGetData] <-> libMyLib <-> [libDoStuff]

I cannot modify libGetData, nor can I change libDoStuff.
libDoStuff has a number of functions that look like:

```
bool isDataGood8(uint8_t input);
bool isDataGood16(uint16_t input);
bool isDataGood32(uint32_t input);
bool isDataGood64(uint64_t input);
```

I just want a clean way to implement an intermediate function between getData() and all types of isDataGoodXX().

```
template <typename T>
T getValue()
{
    // Create intermediate array for getData
    uint8_t temp_array[sizeof(T)];
    // Fill temp_array
    getData(&temp_array, sizeof(T));
    // Create value type to hold byte-array
    T return_val;
    // Copy array data into integer type
    std::memcpy(&return_val, temp_array, sizeof(T));
    return return_val;
}
```

**Is this template a valid solution?**

Comment: you should be careful about alignement

Comment: @Tyker, no alignment issues on sight

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this code is **almost** correct, with a slight exception. Your call to getData should look like:

```
getData(temp_array, sizeof(T));
```

You should not be passing the address of **array** into your getValue function. Other than that, it is good, and it doesn't suffer from quite common strict aliasing violation.

You are also avoiding any issues of alignment, and the code is as optimal as can be give the API.

Comment: If `std::is_same<unsigned char*, uint8_t*>{}` holds, can we then avoid the `memcpy`? As far as I understand it, the strict aliasing does not apply to `unsigned char*`. Assembly [can be different](https://godbolt.org/g/mL4kuL).

Comment: @Julius, yes, for the platforms where `uint8_t` is an alias for `[unsigned] char`, you can read directly into the object.

Answer (score 0):

A problem I see is that because you are only templating the returned value, you will need to explicitly specify the type to use your template method, i.e.

```
auto val = getValue<uint32_t>();
isDataGood(val); // Should be!
```

Without using auto, this is prone to mismatch errors, not all of which will be reported:

```
uint32_t val = getValue<uint16_t>();
isDataGood(val); // perhaps not!
```

It depends how heavy-handed you want to be to protect against this, but one way is to make the returned value a parameter, which allows template type deduction:

```
uint32_t val;
getValue(val);
isDataGood(val); // Must be!
```

Another is to not use raw integers, but always a struct containing the value as a member of the right size. You can't trivially switch between structs like you can between integer sizes.

Another is to have getValue return a wrapper that for a given type knows how to cast to it, and for other types, fails to cast at compile time:

```
struct FailIntBase 
{
  operator uint8_t()const = delete;
  operator uint16_t()const = delete;
  operator uint32_t()const = delete;
  operator uint64_t()const = delete;
  // etc
};
template <class Castable> struct SafeInt: FailIntBase
{
  Castable val;
  SafeInt(Castable val): val(val) {}
  operator Castable()const
  { return val; }
};

template <typename T>
SafeInt<T> getValue() { //...

// Testing:
auto X = getValue<uint16_t>();
uint16_t Y = getValue<uint16_t>();
uint32_t Z = getValue<uint16_t>(); //error: use of deleted function 'FailIntBase::operator uint32_t() const'
```

If you need to cover more types including signed types, you can get away with a much smaller implementation of FailIntBase if you can live with the less informative error message:

```
conversion from 'SafeInt<short unsigned int>' to 'uint32_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} is ambiguous
note: candidate: 'SafeInt<Castable>::operator Castable() const [with Castable = short unsigned int]'
note: candidate: 'FailIntBase::operator uint64_t() const' <deleted>
```